# svn status see file copy source

Tags: svn

In my working copy, say I run this:

```
$ svn cp foo.cpp bar.cpp
```

When I `svn st`, it shows that bar.cpp was copied.

```
$ svn st 
A + bar.cpp
```

But how can I find out that bar.cpp is a copy of foo.cpp?  How can I get the name of the original file before I commit?

Answer (score 3):

A coworker and I found the answer -

```
$ svn info bar.cpp | grep '^Copied From URL:'
Copied From URL: svn://myserver.com/path/to/file/foo.cpp
```